# Should closed questions with accepted answers be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, accepted-answer

I have come across a few questions that are already closed but have an accepted answer. Being relatively new here, I'd thought I'd ask this question.

Examples: [Here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26443/anime-with-a-red-haired-female-protagonist-who-is-like-a-mutant), and [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26079/looking-for-an-ecchi-manga-in-which-the-students-of-a-school-arent-allowed-to-w) being the more recent cases (there are definitely more [actual questions that are not the usual image search requests, usually id-reqs])

My question comes from the fact that the question has too scant details for a normal question and answer (as per guidelines), thus invoking the close votes. Yet, despite that, it is answerable (as can be seen from the fact that there is an **accepted** answer.

One of the questions I have voted to close myself, which resulted in my consideration of voting to reopen, but I am not sure.

There are of course repercussions - being unsearchable is one (I'm not familiar enough to know if there are more) and perhaps a small detail is all that's needed for a potential asker to link it to their memory to search for a similar (and scantly detailed) question.

Comment: Question should be reopened only if the question improved itself rather then based on its answer or being accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't close questions based on the answers, nor do we reopen them on such basis.

Even if the question has an acceptable answer, if it's off-topic it's off topic, and it should be closed. A closed question is also a signpost for future visitors that say "See this question? We don't want questions like that", which is still true about the question, regardless of the answer it may have.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply but I was away for awhile. What about questions that "have too little detail to be answered" but yet in the face of it being so it has been? The problem is that "too little detail" is an opinion, but "ability to be answered" is a fact. (ie the reason the question is closed is invalid)

Comment: @Tyhja: "Too little detail" according to our [criteria](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions). It's not an opinion as much as it is a consensus by the community. The fact that someone answered it doesn't mean it fits the criteria set forth by the site.